# Version string comparision using the ternary operator in C

Tags: c, ternary-operator

I need to compare two "version" strings which may or may not end with `.0`, so that (for example) `10.3.8.9.2` and `10.3.8.9.2.0` are considered to be equal.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <string.h>

int main()    
{

   char str1[20];
   char str2[20];
   int ret;

   strcpy(str1, "10.3.8.9.2");
   strcpy(str2, "10.3.8.9.2.0");
   // strcpy(str2, "10.3.8.9.20.0");  This case are invalid case and need to handle properly inside ternary operator

   ret=(strlen(str1)> strlen(str2))? strncmp( str1,str2,strlen(str2)):(strncmp( str1,str2,strlen(str1))&&( strlen(str2)==strlen(str1)+2 ));

   //printf("ret=%d", ret);

   //ret=(strlen(str1)> strlen(str2))? strncmp( str1,str2,strlen(str2)):(strncmp( str1,str2,strlen(str1)));

   printf("ret_value=%d", ret);

   return 0;

}
```

The code above treats `10.3.8.9.2` and `10.3.8.9.20.0` as equal, which is incorrect. I have tried to update the code as shown below, but it is not giving desired result due to `strncmp()` returning `0` when it is successful.

It seems that I am not handling this condition properly inside the ternary operator. It may be that storing the return value of both expressions in separate variables can resolve this issue, but would like to know how this can be achieved using the ternary operator.

Comment: Note: you probably want `versionsort()` [extension to the standard library in BSD and linux]

Comment: yes you are right, I want to validate the same by ignoring the .0

Comment: versionsort() doesn't give desire result.

Comment: Chop off all trailing `".0"`s and compare.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the shortest common sub-string of `str1` and `str2` first, and then check the remainder of each string after that. Here's a solution that doesn't use the ternary operator for the string comparison:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_versions(const char *a, const char *b)
{

    size_t len1, len2, shortest;

    // Return a negative value for invalid inputs.
    if (!a || !b) { return -1; }

    //First, get the length of the shortest string.
    len1 = strlen(a);
    len2 = strlen(b);
    shortest = len1 < len2 ? len1 : len2;

    // If the first sections of the strings are different, they do not match.    
    if (strncmp(a, b, shortest) != 0) { return 0; }

    // Otherwise, check each string: if an "extension" exists, it must be ".0".
    if (a[shortest] && strcmp(&a[shortest], ".0") != 0) { return 0; }
    if (b[shortest] && strcmp(&b[shortest], ".0") != 0) { return 0; }

    // If both strings end with ".0" or nothing, they match.
    return 1;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    printf("Return value: %d\n", compare_versions("10.3.8.9.2", "10.3.8.9.2"));
    printf("Return value: %d\n", compare_versions("10.3.8.9.2.0", "10.3.8.9.2.0"));
    printf("Return value: %d\n", compare_versions("10.3.8.9.2.0", "10.3.8.9.2"));
    printf("Return value: %d\n", compare_versions("10.3.8.9.2", "10.3.8.9.2.0"));
    printf("Return value: %d\n", compare_versions("10.3.8.9.20", "10.3.8.9.2"));
    return 0;
}
```

You can run the above code online [here](http://codepad.org/W28kx7ma). If you really need to use the ternary operator, the string comparison logic could be re-organised, though I'm not sure that it would be as readable.

Comment: what about `str1 = "10.3.8.09.2"` `"str2 = 10.3.8.9.02.0"`
shouldn't it be 1  ?

Comment: This was not stated as a requirement in the original post, which is why the code I have given doesn't account for it.

Comment: leading 0 is valid case as single digit can be represented leading single 0 following by single digit .Ali's code takes care of all the scenarios properly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int a[10],b[10];

   char str1[20];
   char str2[20];

   int kase;
   printf("Enter number of cases : ");
   scanf("%d",&kase);
   getchar();

   while(kase--)
   {
       // initialize array values to 0 if you have to do this checking more than once
       memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
       memset(b,0,sizeof(b));

       //strcpy(str1, "10.3.8.09.2.0");
       //strcpy(str2, "10.3.8.9.02.0");
       printf("Enter first string : ");
       gets(str1);
       printf("Enter second string : ");
       gets(str2);

       int ind1=0,ind2=0;

       char *token=strtok(str1,".");
       while(token!=NULL)
       {
           a[ind1++]=atoi(token); // separating the first string with respect to '.'
           token=strtok(NULL,".");
       }

       token=strtok(str2,".");
       while(token!=NULL)
       {
           b[ind2++]=atoi(token); // separating the 2nd string with respect to '.'
           token=strtok(NULL,".");
       }

       int same=1,n=ind1;
       if(ind2>n)  // selecting maximum values between str1 and str2
         n=ind2;
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           if(a[i]!=b[i])
           {
               same=0;
               break;
           }
       }

       if(same)
         printf("value = 1 . Strings are same\n");
       else
         printf("value = 0 . Strings not same\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Here every string value is converted to integer so it will be easy to compare among them.

And this also will work for cases like this :

```
10.03.8.09.2.00
10.3.8.09.002
```

that is where numbers can have leading zero's :)

Comment: Note that it's recommended to use [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html) instead of [`atoi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atoi.html) if you're not certain that the input will definitely contain numbers.

Comment: version number always contains numbers

Comment: How do you know? The op hasn't stated where he gets the strings from - they might be entered by a user, or extracted from a file name.

Comment: May be... no offense :) but if it contains only numbers and can contain leading 0's then above solution is perfect

Comment: Additionally, `int a[10],b[10];` may not be zero (though they usually are) and the `while(token!=NULL)` lines should probably check to see if `ind1` and `ind2` are less than 10, or they could go over the end of the `int` arrays.

Comment: Hey listen...
it's not the final solution...
if OP thinks his array size can be bigger he can change it statically... not a big deal

Comment: It looks good if we compare only single source and destination strings. what if comparison is done under loop with so many pair of source and destination strings. I did the same and found it doesn't work due to strtok function evil behavior. in my case all (near about 45) source and destination pair were stored in link list and what I found after first comparison for next iteration it started taking source string .1 ( only first 2 character of string) because of strtok function.

Comment: @user2907032 It's because `array a[10] and b[10]` value changes after one iteration...
all you have to do is, initialize them 0 again, after each iteration...
i edited the answer. Check it. It will work

Comment: I already tried the same by locally setting the value  int a[20]={0,};
 int  b[20]={0,};even globally tried and observe the same behavior.

Comment: use memset() as i answered. It will work. You can give your code. Then i can say whats wrong happening :)

Comment: memset doesn't work  , still I am able to see (.1) value only for first string and due to this all other validation were getting failed except one. below change in your code works fine.

Comment: while(*str1)
      {
     if (isdigit(*str1)) {

         val = strtol(str1, &str1, 10);
        a[ind1++]=val;
        

      }
      str1++;
      }   Apart from this in else part we can also validate whether string contains numerical value or not.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing :(
But if there are multiple cases like you said, then my edited code will definitely work...
if not then give me the sample example, for which it fails

Comment: entire code I can't share here ,due to some constraints :(. you were using strtok function to get the numeric digit , same way I am using strtol function to get the digit separately. After first comparison I observed below behavior in logs for other iterations. versioncmp| version comparision not successfull |first=.1
versioncmp| version comparision not successfull |second=10.3.8.09.2.0

versioncmp|compare1 len= 2

versioncmp| compare2 len=13

Comment: i don't know what you are meaning :(
it works fine in every cases for me...
may be you can send me the code if you want... my email : mail2aliakber@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

An arithmetic approach that also validates the versions as sets of numbers.

Each field can be 0 to 9999, leading 0's optional.

```
int ValidateVersion(const char *src, unsigned long long *number) {
  unsigned u[5];
  int n4 = 0;
  int n5 = 0;
  sscanf(src,"%4u.%4u.%4u.%4u %n.%4u %n", 
    &u[0], &u[1], &u[2], &u[3], &n5, &u[4], &n5);

  if (n5 > 0) {
    if (src[n5] != '\0' || u[4] != 0) return -1; // invalid
  } else if (n4 != 0) {
    return -1; // invalid
  }  
  *number = u[0] * 1000000000000u + u[1] * 100000000u + u[2] * 10000u + u[3];
}

const char *sample() {
  const char *str1 = "10.3.8.9.2";
  unsigned long long n1;
  if (ValidateVersion(str1, &n1) return "1 Invalid";

  const char *str2 = "10.3.8.9.2.0";
  unsigned long long n2;
  if (ValidateVersion(str2, &n2) return "2 Invalid";

  if (n1 == n2) return "Equal";
  return "Different";
}
```

Comment: Note that `u[0] * 1000000000000u` will produce numbers so large that they require more than 32-bits to store, hence the use of `unsigned long long` above. However, `unsigned long long` is not available in C90, which might be something that you need to consider.

Comment: @GoBusto Earlier C does not support prototypes which are used here and in your post - so how far back shall code compatibility go, why stop at C89/90?  Making code compatible with pre-C99 compilers, though admirable, is 2+ generations back in the C standard.

Comment: I only pointed this out because I was recently asked for help by someone whose compiler (for various reasons) couldn't compile their code as C99, so they were restricted to the limitations of C90. I'm not saying that your answer is wrong in any way - I'm simply pointing out that C99 is required, in case the OP (or anyone else who comes across this question in search of an answer) is similarly restricted. Also, I'm pretty sure that C90 does support prototypes (the code in my answer was tested using GCC in C90 mode) unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementation. NOTE: I use the standard retrun value convention for `strcmp()` Equal strings : return value = zero)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_versions(const char *a, const char *b)
{
size_t lena, lenb, len;
int rc;

            /* handle NULL pointer arguments gracefully */
if (!a || !b) { return (a) ? 1 : (b) ? -1: 0; }

while(1) {
            /* find the length of the non-numerical prefix */
    lena = strcspn(a, "0123456789" );
    lenb = strcspn(b, "0123456789" );

    len = (lena <lenb) ? lena : lenb;
    rc = (len) ? memcmp(a,b, len): 0;
    if (rc) return rc;

            /* Skip leading zeros */
    for(a += lena; *a == '0'; a++) {;}
    for(b += lenb; *b == '0'; b++) {;}
    if (!*a || !*b) break;

            /* find the length of the numerical prefix */
    lena = strspn(a, "0123456789" );
    lenb = strspn(b, "0123456789" );
    if (lena != lenb) return lena-lenb;

    rc = (len) ? memcmp(a,b, lena): 0;
    if (rc) return rc;

    a += lena; b += lenb;
    }

return *a - *b;
}


struct pair {
    char *l;
    char *r;
    } pairs[] = {
    {"10.3.8.9.2", "10.3.8.9.2"},
    {"10.3.8.9.2.0", "10.3.8.9.2.0"},
    {"10.3.8.9.2.0", "10.3.8.9.2"},
    {"10.3.8.9.2", "10.3.8.9.2.0"},
    {"10.3.8.9.2", "10.3.8.9.02"},
    {"10.3.8.9.20", "10.3.8.9.2"},
    {"10.3.8.9.2", "10.3.8.9.03"},
    {"10.3.8.9.2", "10.3.8.9.01"},
    {"10.3.8.9.02", "10.3.8.9.3"},
    {"10.3.8.9.02", "10.3.8.9.1"},
    {"10.3.8.9.02", "10.3.8.9.03"},
    {"10.3.8.9.02", "10.3.8.9.01"},
        };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int ii;

for (ii=0; ii < 12; ii++) {
    int rc;
    rc = compare_versions(pairs[ii].l ,pairs[ii].r  );
    printf("(%s <-->> %s)  compare value= %d\n"
        , pairs[ii].l ,pairs[ii].r  , rc);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
(10.3.8.9.2 <-->> 10.3.8.9.2)  compare value= 0
(10.3.8.9.2.0 <-->> 10.3.8.9.2.0)  compare value= 0
(10.3.8.9.2.0 <-->> 10.3.8.9.2)  compare value= 0
(10.3.8.9.2 <-->> 10.3.8.9.2.0)  compare value= 0
(10.3.8.9.2 <-->> 10.3.8.9.02)  compare value= 0
(10.3.8.9.20 <-->> 10.3.8.9.2)  compare value= 1
(10.3.8.9.2 <-->> 10.3.8.9.03)  compare value= -1
(10.3.8.9.2 <-->> 10.3.8.9.01)  compare value= 1
(10.3.8.9.02 <-->> 10.3.8.9.3)  compare value= -1
(10.3.8.9.02 <-->> 10.3.8.9.1)  compare value= 1
(10.3.8.9.02 <-->> 10.3.8.9.03)  compare value= -1
(10.3.8.9.02 <-->> 10.3.8.9.01)  compare value= 1
```